# Querying with LINQ and EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to search through a database to return the company names that are in a city the user enters.

The method I've created works and does what it's supposed to, however, there are two issues:

1. It's printing a line 6 times instead of just once in the first `foreach` statement.
2. It's not returning the right amount of customers in the first `foreach` statement.

Here's the full method:

```
static void ReturnCities()
{
    WriteLine("Enter the name of a city: ");
    string? city = ReadLine();

    using (var db = new Northwind())
    {
        // query to find all customers in the
        // city that was entered
        var query = db.Customers
                      .Where(customer => customer.City == city)
                      .Select(customer => new
                              {
                                  customer.City
                              });

        // prints a statement with how many customers
        // are in the city entered
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            WriteLine("There are {0} customers in {1}: ",
                      arg0: item.City.Count(),
                      arg1: item.City);
        }

        // query to return a list of all customers 
        // in the city entered       
        var query2 = db.Customers
                       .Where(customer => customer.City == city)
                       .Select(customer => new
                               {
                                   customer.CompanyName
                               });

        foreach (var item2 in query2)
        {
            WriteLine($"    {item2.CompanyName} ");
        }
    }
}
```

The output for this currently is:

```
Enter the name of a city: 
London
There are 6 customers in London: 
There are 6 customers in London: 
There are 6 customers in London:
There are 6 customers in London:
There are 6 customers in London:
There are 6 customers in London:
    Around the Horn
    B's Beverages
    Consolidated Holdings
    Eastern Connection
    North/South
    Seven Seas Imports
```

I'm not sure what's causing the first issue other than the `foreach` statement possibly because it's returning a print statement for each item in the query, but I haven't been able to fix it.

The second issue I'm currently still trying to fix but any and all tips for both issues are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will just return `Your query will just return an IQueryable<string> { "london", "london", "london" }` because of the `Select()`.

You could simply do 1 query for your code ...

```
var query = db.Customers
    .Where(customer => new() {
        customer.City,
        customer.CompanyName
    });

var count = query.Count();
// output: 6

foreach(var customer in query) 
{
    Console.Writeline(customer.CompanyName);
}

// output:
//    Around the Horn
//    B's Beverages
//    Consolidated Holdings
//    Eastern Connection
//    North/South
//    Seven Seas Imports
```

Comment: Instead of using `query.Count()`, materialize the query first with either `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` and then use the array/list count.

Comment: I couldn't fully get the query you posted to work, but setting the var count like you posted and then removing the foreach statement around the "There are {} customers in {}:" fixed the issue! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @TheStudentMans Try adding .ToList() after the Select()